# Separating tags in dirty data in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
Column1 Column2 Tags                      Column3
str1    str2    owner:u1,env:prod1        str3
str2    str4    env:prod2,env:prod2       str6
str1    str3                              str7
str3    str4    dwdws:qsded,ewe:22w       str8
```

I cant filter the data based on Tags and clear out that is not in proper tags format since I need the whole data set. Please Note:

- Third row, Tags column is already filtered as empty string
- There may be repetitions in the key:value pairs.

I need to have Tags that I am interested in as a separate columns something like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Tags                      Column3  Owner env
str1    str2    owner:u1,env:prod1        str3     u1    prod1
str2    str4    env:prod2,env:prod2       str6           prod2
str1    str3                              str7     
str3    str4    dwdws:qsded,ewe:22w       str8
```

I tried along the lines as:

```
Data['owner']=Data['Tags'].str.slice(Data.Tags.str.find('owner:'),Data.Tags.str.find('owner:')+<length until comma after owner is reached>)
```

I get all NaN values in the column. I am hoping there is a one or two liner to filter this out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic method would be to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the key:value pairs, then to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df.join(df['Tags'].str.extractall('([^:,]+):([^:,]+)')
         .droplevel('match').pivot(columns=0, values=1))
       )
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2                 Tags Column3  dwdws   env  ewe owner
0    str1    str2    owner:u1,env:prod    str3    NaN  prod  NaN    u1
1    str2    str4             env:prod    str6    NaN  prod  NaN   NaN
2    str1    str3                  NaN    str7    NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
3    str3    str4  dwdws:qsded,ewe:22w    str8  qsded   NaN  22w   NaN
```

If you want to restrict the tags, adapt the first part of the regex:

```
out = (df.join(df['Tags'].str.extractall('(owner|env):([^:,]+)')
         .droplevel('match').pivot(columns=0, values=1))
       )
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2                 Tags Column3   env owner
0    str1    str2    owner:u1,env:prod    str3  prod    u1
1    str2    str4             env:prod    str6  prod   NaN
2    str1    str3                  NaN    str7   NaN   NaN
3    str3    str4  dwdws:qsded,ewe:22w    str8   NaN   NaN
```

##### handling duplicated keys

```
out = (df.join(df['Tags'].str.extractall('(owner|env):([^:,]+)')
               .droplevel('match').reset_index()
               .pivot_table(index='index', columns=0, values=1, aggfunc='first')
              )
       )
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the solution. I understand using extractall and droplevel but after that step, my index is not unique for each row and pivot does not work. I tried adding reset_index() before pivot but then I can't join since indexes are not the same and can not be used as keys.

Comment: Then please provide a fully reproducible input as DataFrame constructor that reproduces this issue (including the duplicated key:value pairs if any)

Comment: Thanks, I found a problem with the dataset and the solution. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Murat there is `prod` in the input and `prod1`/`prod2` in the output, is this normal?

Comment: See the update to handle duplicated keys (it keeps only the first value), you can easily change to have the last, or to aggregate as list/concatenation/etc.

Comment: Have you tested the update?

Comment: This solution did not work because data is too dirty to use a one liner. However I marked as accepted since it can be useful for others. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Murat oh, that's too bad. I hope you'll manage to find a way. Don't hesitate to ask a follow-up question with a more complex example.